# Segmentation fault error - C programming

Tags: c++

I am receiving a Segmentation Fault error when I run this program. To summarize, the program reads in multiple data files (129 of them). Each file contains information about a specific name. The information includes how many people were named a specific name in a specific year and the gender. For now, I am trying to store each name in a linked list. Whenever I read in more than about 4 data files, I get the Segmentation Fault error. I have written this program in Java, which was much simpler. If anybody could simply point me in the right direction, as I am almost certain this has to do with memory allocation, but I cannot seem to solve this myself. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//typedef struct Node NodeStruct;
struct Node {
  char *namePtr;
  Node *nextPtr;
};

int main() {
  // Declare variables 
  Node *headPtr = NULL;
  Node *tempPtr;
  Node *currentPtr;

  // Variables for reading in a file
  FILE *filePtr;
  char fileName[20];
  int i;
  int nameLength;
  char inputLine[81];

  cout << "Reading from data files, please be patient...\n";

  // Loop through files
  for (i = 1880; i <= 2009; i++) {
    sprintf(fileName, "data/yob%d.txt", i);
    filePtr = fopen(fileName, "r");    // Open the file
    // Check to ensure file was opened
    if(filePtr == NULL) {
      cout << "Error opening input file...check location of data files\n";
      exit(-1);   // Exit program
    } // End if statement

    while (fscanf(filePtr, "%s", inputLine) != EOF) {

      // Create a node
      tempPtr = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
      tempPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

      // Set the head pointer of first node
      if (headPtr == NULL) {
    headPtr = tempPtr;
    currentPtr = tempPtr;
      } // End if statement

      // Link the list
      currentPtr->nextPtr = tempPtr;
      currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;

      // Create pointer variables
      char *startPtr = inputLine;
      char *endPtr = NULL;

      endPtr = strchr(inputLine, ',');   // Point to end of name
      int length = endPtr - inputLine;      // Calculate length
      // Create space for the name
      tempPtr->namePtr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(length + 1));
      strncpy(tempPtr->namePtr, startPtr, length); // Store pointer to name
      //      cout << tempPtr->namePtr << endl;

    }
  } // End of for (i = 1880...
  cout << "Done reading from data files...\n";
} // End of main function
```

Comment: Please fix your format and ask a question.

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see where the fault is generated?

Comment: This is not `C`; it is more `C++`, but even then it's a `C++` with a very very strange accent.

Comment: This is not a C program, although most of your constructs are C, in that it has `using namespace std;` and uses iostreams.

Comment: I understand this brings C and C++ together. That is actually the point of this program. Thank you all for your comments and help, this has been solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely

```
tempPtr->namePtr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(length + 1));
```

should be

```
tempPtr->namePtr = (char *) malloc(length + 1);
```

since you copy that many characters to the string.  `sizeof (length + 1)` would evaluate to four on a 32-bit machine (eight on 64-bit).  Not enough memory was being allocated, so the `strncpy` which followed this was overwriting memory not belonging to you.

Comment: Wow, not sure how I missed that or why I would try to write it that way, thank you much.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than find your bug, let's try to teach you some practical lessons. Here are my C++ rules for C programmers:

1) Don't use pointers to track your data. The standard containers work just fine for that.

2) Don't use pointers to manage your strings. The standard string type works just fine for that.

3) Don't use pointers for anything else, until you need to learn how polymorphism works.

4) Don't use malloc at all. Ever.

5) Don't use new, hardly at all.

The neat thing about not using pointers (or arrays), is that you will never make pointer bugs. No more buffer overflows, no more segmentation faults. Joy!

Here is my translation of your program into idiomatic C++. Because I let `std::list` do all of the list management, all of the silly headPtr, nextPtr, etc, goes away. Because I let `std::string` do all of the string management, I don't need to `malloc(strlen())` (or fix my bug and `malloc(strlen()+1)`. Because I use the RAII idiom, I don't have to worry about closing my files.

It all just works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::list;
using std::ifstream;
using std::stringstream;

int main() {
  // Declare variables 
  list<string> list;

  cout << "Reading from data files, please be patient...\n";

  // Loop through files
  for (int i = 1880; i <= 2009; i++) {
    stringstream fileName;
    fileName << "data/yob" << i << ".txt";
    ifstream filePtr(fileName.str().c_str());

    if(!filePtr.is_open()) {
      cout << "Error opening input file: " << fileName.str() << " ...check location of data files\n";
      exit(-1);   // Exit program
    }

    string inputLine;
    while (filePtr >> inputLine) {
      list.push_back(inputLine);
    }
  } // End of for (i = 1880...
  cout << "Done reading from data files...\n";
} // End of main function
```

Comment: Adams: Thank you for your reply. I agree with everything you have brought up, the reason I have gone about and written the program this was is because it was required. I am new to pointers, and I want to ensure I am able to wrap my brain around them. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you please expand a bit about how you are using RAII (or rather ifstream is I guess?) in this case?

Comment: @Max - I just mean to say that `ifstream` uses RAII. That is, it opens the file during its construction and closes the file during its destruction. Since I am using a local ifstream object (remember - I avoid `new`) I know that the file will be closed when the local variable `filePtr` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is already answered, but you should also be in the habit of closing your files.  For you with something like `fclose(filePtr)`.  By the way if you learn how to use `std::ifstream` then you don't have to close, it auto closes when the `std::ifstream` goes out of scope.

Comment: By the way, there is an easy-to-use RAII idiom even for fopen/fclose : `boost::shared_ptr<FILE> filePtr(fopen("in.txt", "r"), fclose);`